# Vlookup Excel, Referencing A different Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to create a simple VLOOKUP function for my spreadsheet using the below:
In the first sheet

```
=VLOOKUP("Salary",'December 2015_natwest_download'!$D$4:$E$43,1,FALSE)
```

This is the sheet i am trying to reference:

The sheet I am trying reference:

```
Value          Category
======= ==========
£530.00        Charlotte Owing
-£53.00        Gym
-£16.47        Water
-£67.00        Phone
-£11.01        Presents
-£14.40        Eating out
-£100.00       Food
-£65.00        Other
```

But when I put the VLOOKUP code into my excel, it returns NA. Can anyone see what is causing the error?

Comment: Firstly, "December" is misspelt not sure if this is just in this question or whether it is in the formula on the workbook but might be worth checking. Secondly, do you have "Salary" as a named range?

Comment: That is awful spelling by me, but that isn't causing the error as far as I can see. And again, sorry about the formatting, but Salary is definitely part of the names range, I just truncated it to make my life easier.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(LookupValue,LookupTable, columnindex,MatchType)`

Comment: If "Salary" is a named range you don't need the speech marks around the word. Also, you've specified the column that you want the values of as column 1 (which would be `Column D` in the range you've stated). If the `Salary` cannot be found in `Column D` the formula will produce `#N/A`.

Comment: Your lookup_table refers to $D$4:$E$43 which is 40 rows, but you only have 8 rows of sample data. Is your sample data in Columns D and E? To use vlookup, the value your looking up needs to be to the left of the value you're hoping to return.

Comment: Thanks for all your help:
I have edited the code, and it now returns  #NAME:

I have changed the columns around to make the value I am searching for to the left of the £ value:

So the value that I want to return is now column 5.

My code is now

`=VLOOKUP(Salary,'December 2015_natwest_download'!D4:E43,5,FALSE)`

Comment: Double check `Salary` - that's all that will return the #NAME error in your formula. What cell is it referencing?  Once that's working you'll get a #REF error as your lookup range is two columns - D & E and you're asking it to look at column 5 of those two columns.

Comment: When you specify the column you are specifying the column number within the range you have referred to in the formula, as the range you have referred to `December 2015_natwest_download'!D4:E43` is only a 2 column range you need to either have 1 or 2 as the column, if you want the data from `Column E` you need to have this set to 2 (as its the second column in the specified range). For example: `=VLOOKUP(Salary,'December 2015_natwest_download'!D4:E43,2,FALSE)`. Also, the `#NAME` error is likely caused by `Salary` not being a named range, try replacing this with a value or cell reference.

Comment: If the lookup column is to the right of the data to be returned, you need an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair, not a [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). VLOOKUP can only return data that is to the right of the column to lookup.

Comment: Thanks! I referenced the cell, instead of writing salary, and it work. Is there a reason that this is the case? Do cells always need to be referenced?

On another note, if more that one value appears, can the net total be used in the cell?

Comment: When you use "Salary" (with the quotes), you instruct the VLOOKUP to search for exactly that - the text "Salary".  If you want to search for the value present in another cell, you refer to that cell, like e.g. A1.  When you have named that cell, you can also refer to that cell by that name, but then without the quotes, since quotes makes it a piece of text and not a cell reference.

Comment: If you want the total, just use a `SUMIF` formula e.g. `=SUMIF('December 2015_natwest_download'!$D$4:$D$43,Salary,'December 2015_natwest_download'!$E$4:$E$43)`. Obviously change `Salary` for the cell reference. This formula will calculate the `SUM` of cells E4 to E43 if the data in `Column D` matches the `Salary`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is designed to lookup a value on the far left of a block of data and return a corresponding value from a column to the right.

If you need to lookup a value and return a value from a corresponding column **to the left** of the lookup column, you need to use an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair.

If you are returning numbers based on a condition (either in that column or another column) either the [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) or 
[SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) function will do. Individual entries can be easily collected but if there is more than a single match to your condition, you will receive a sum total of the matching numbers.

[image: index_match_salary]

The formulas in E4:F4 are,

```
=INDEX('December 2015_natwest_download'!A:A, MATCH(D4, 'December 2015_natwest_download'!B:B, 0))
=SUMIFS('December 2015_natwest_download'!A:A,'December 2015_natwest_download'!B:B, D4)
```

Note that the SUMIFS in F5 is returning two *Gym* entries.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help :)