# Compare two excel sheets and copy data to sheet1

Tags: excel, vlookup

This is what I am trying to do...I am very new to Excel and have never created a VLOOKUP code before....two sheets in same excel project.

compare column A from TM Roster to Column B in Sheet2, if it matches, copy Column G from Sheet2 to Column X in TM Roster

I have tried looking at other answers, but I do not know how to change the code/formula to make it work in my workbook.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vlookup Excel, Referencing A different Sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853219/vlookup-excel-referencing-a-different-sheet)

Comment: The Microsoft documentation literally spells out how the formula works `=VLOOKUP(Value you want to look up, range where you want to lookup the value, the column number in the range containing the return value, Exact Match or Approximate Match – indicated as 0/FALSE or 1/TRUE).`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using index/match instead, because it is much easier to use:

> =INDEX(Column you want to return value form,MATCH(Cell you want to compare,Column you want to compare it against,Match value 0))

In your case the formula  for field X1 would look like this:

> =INDEX(Sheet2!G:G,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!B:B,0))

Once the formula has been pasted you can just drag it down.